# How to convert BIGINT to TIMESTAMPZ in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

Using:

- PostgreSQL 14 in Supabase
- Grafana cloud

I am trying to convert `BIGINT` timestamp in milliseconds to `TIMESTAMPZ` in `PostgreSQL 14`.

The `BIGINT` is a constant stored in a `$__to` and `$__from`. I am trying to query data in a certain time range with this query:

```
SELECT
  "timestamp" AS "time",
  etalon,
  humidity,
  temperature
FROM "values"
WHERE
  timestamp >= TO_TIMESTAMP($__from, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  and timestamp <  TO_TIMESTAMP($__to, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

The query above result in this error:

```
function to_timestamp(bigint, unknown) does not exist
```

I have looked into these topics but couldn't find a solution that would work:

1. [Postgres timestamp to unix time in milliseconds as a bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978350/postgres-timestamp-to-unix-time-in-milliseconds-as-a-bigint)
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215354/convert-date-format-into-bigint-format-in-postgresql
3. [How to format bigint field into a date in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485502/how-to-format-bigint-field-into-a-date-in-postgresql)

### Edit

Using [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485539/11101156) solution doesn't work either:

```
SELECT
  "timestamp" AS "time",
  etalon,
  humidity,
  temperature
FROM "values"
WHERE
  timestamp >= TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1644770125499 / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  and timestamp <  TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1644770125499 / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Results in:

```
operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone >= text
```

Using suggestion from comments I do convert the BIGINT but I get weird looking timestamp:

[image]

Type of my timestampz column:

[image]

Comment: If your column `timestamp` is a unix epoch, you need to convert **that** using `to_timestamp()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219890/how-to-convert-unix-epoch-to-a-timestamp

Comment: I have edited the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Is your `timestamp` column a `varchar`? If it's not (but a proper `timestamp` data type), then all you need is `"timestamp" >= TO_TIMESTAMP(1644770125499 / 1000)`

Comment: I don't know - editor doesn't say if its a varchar (look at picture in the question).

Comment: Well, apparently it **is** a  `timestamptz` so there is no need to convert the timestamp from `to_timestamp()` into a text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the single-argument form of `to_timestamp`:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1644853209.6);

       to_timestamp       
══════════════════════════
 2022-02-14 16:40:09.6+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: Man you just saved me! :) Thank you a lot!